# Как исправить указанную выше синтаксическую ошибку в PHP?

Tags: php

Я пытался решить
Ошибка, но безуспешно

Прилагается ошибка и соответствующий код:

Ошибка:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /var/www/html/arango4.php on line 42
```

Соответствующий код:

```
foreach ($a as &$value) {
    $s = json_decode($value, true);
    if($s['sender'] == $_REQUEST['sender']){
        print $s['sender'];
        print '\t';
        print $s['to'];
        print '\t';
        print $s['text'];
        print '<hr>';
        //if ($s['time']!=null){
            //$D=time()-intval($s['time']);
            //print ($D);
        //}
        print '</div>';
    }  
?>
```

Мне бы хотелось найти быстрое решение, которое я пытался решить в течение многих часов, но безуспешно.

Comment: если вы будете нормально форматировать код, расставляя отступы, то труда не составит заметить отсутствие одной из закрывающих скобок

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибки типа "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file" - сигнализируют отсутствия символа(`}`), отвечающего за конец тела (цикла, условия и функции и т.п). У Вас не закрыта `}` для цикла `foreach`.

Попробуйте так:

```
foreach ($a as &$value) {
    $s = json_decode($value, true);
    if($s['sender'] == $_REQUEST['sender']){
        print $s['sender'];
        print '\t';
        print $s['to'];
        print '\t';
        print $s['text'];
        print '<hr>';
        //if ($s['time']!=null){
            //$D=time()-intval($s['time']);
            //print ($D);
        //}
        print '</div>';
    }  
}
```